# EF6 validation error when trying to make a one-to-one relationship code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm trying to configure a One-to-One relationship between two classes.

```
public class Exercice
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual Sfe Sfe { get; set;}
}
public class Sfe
{
     [ForeignKey("Exercice")]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual Exercice Exercice { get; set; }
}
```

When i run `add-migration` it gives me this error:
`Sfe_Exercice_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Sfe_Exercice_Source' in relationship 'Sfe_Exercice'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.`

Wherever i look this up on the internet, they say that this is the right way to do it, and i even encoutered someone who got the same error and adding the `[ForeignKey()]` attribute on the dependent class solved it for them.
Unfortunately, i get the error even with the `[ForeignKey()]` attribute.
I want to do this using Data Annotations only.

Any help please?

Comment: Does it work when you rename `Id` in your Exercice class to something like `ExerciceId` and the `Id` in you Sfe class to `SfeId` ?

Comment: Put the `ForeignKey` attribute on the navigation property instead. The parameter of the attribute should match a property that stores the Id. (`[ForeignKey(nameof(ExecuteId))]`).

Comment: i tried both of these, but it gives me another error saying that Sfe has no key defined.